# Question about testing React components using CustomHooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-redux

I am just starting to learn React and Redux.
Have a question about how to test in Jest.

I separate the component logic from the function component as CustomHooks and implement them in a separate file from the one that defines the component.
And inside CustomHooks, it uses `useState` and `useDispatch` hooks.

・src/components/counter.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCounter } from 'modules/counter/operators';

const Counter: React.FC = () => {
  const { count, total, handleIncrementClick, handleResetClick } = useCounter();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>total:{total}</p>
      <p>current:{count}</p>
      <button onClinc={handleIncrementClick}>Increment</button>
      <button onClinc={handleResetClick}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

・src/modules/counter/operators.ts

```
import { useState, useCallback, MouseEvent } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { counterActions } from 'modules/counter/slicer';

const useCounter = (): [
  string,
  (e: MouseEvent) => void,
  (e: MouseEvent) => void,
] => {
  const {count, setCount} = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleIncrementClick= useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      setCcount(count + 1);
      dispatch(counterActions.increment({ add: 1 }));
    },
    [count, dispatch]
  );
  const handleResetClick= useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      setCcount(0);
    },
    [count]
  );

  return [count, handleIncrementClick, handleResetClick];
};
```

When implemented in this way, which of the following is a better UnitTest?

1: Write a separate test for only the `useCounter` function that is implemented as CustomHooks and a test for the `Counter` component itself.
(e.g., `useCounter.test.ts` / `counter.test.tsx`)

2: Test only the `Counter` components that use `useCounter` (do not write the UnitTest for `useCounter` itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prefer option two, test only the `Counter` component behavior using [`react-testing-library`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library). Using hooks is an implementation detail, and testing the behavior of the component in an "integration" test is the way to go in this case. Testing this way will also reflect the way the final user is going to use your component.

However, this changes if you're creating a hook that you're going to publish to reuse by other developers. In this case the hook will be part of your package API, so it should be tested individually.

I must also say that this is a matter of personal preferences, and there is people that prefers to unit test everything.

Comment: Well, I guess we need to find the right place to start for each project.
I'm a private developer of React applications for learning and am small in scale, so like you, I'm going to test with option 2 for now.
You're absolutely right about "personal preference", and I'm sure the rules are different for each company and team.

I asked the question because I was worried that it might not be a good idea to do a test like option 2

That was very helpful, thank you!